# Laravel - Policy custom messages on not authorized not working as expected

Tags: laravel, permissions, policy

So basically I am trying to do a custom deny message when the user is not authorized to do a action like delete/destroy a user. I can't seem to customize the message, I always get the default one saying:

```
Error
Request failed with status code 403
```

In my example I have a UserPolicy and the contents of the destroy method here is this:

```
public function delete(User $user, User $model)
{
    $totalAdmins = User::whereHas('roles', function ($query) {
        $query->where('name', 'administrator');
    })->count();

    // If there is only one administrator, then the user cannot delete it
    if ($totalAdmins === 1 && $model->hasRole('administrator')) {
        return Response::deny('You cannot delete the only administrator.');
    }

    // Admins cannot delete other admins
    if ($user->hasRole('administrator') && $model->hasRole('administrator')) {
        return Response::deny('You cannot delete other administrators.');
    }

    // Only users with the 'delete users' permission can delete users
    if (!$user->hasPermissionTo('delete users')) {
        return Response::deny('You do not have permission to delete users.');
    }

    return Response::allow();
}
```

I also tried the `Gate::inspect(...)` way, but I always end up with the same default message.

Don't know if this information is needed, but the alert/notification is done by axios catch method.

```
this.$axios.delete(url, {
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
    },
}).then(response => {
    /* ... */
}).catch(response => {
    this.$swal.fire({
        title: 'Error',
        text: response.message,
        icon: 'error',
        timer: 3000,
        showConfirmButton: false,
        toast: true,
        timerProgressBar: true,
        hideClass: {
            popup: 'animate__animated animate__fadeOutUp',
        },
        showClass: {
            popup: 'animate__animated animate__fadeInDown',
        },
        position: 'top-end'
    });
});
```

And lastly this is how I do it in the controller to authorize:

`$this->authorize('delete', $user);`

Am I doing something wrong here or missing something?

Edit: the whole `destroy()` method from my `UserController`

```
public function destroy($user)
{
    # Put users to array
    $users = explode(',', $user);

    foreach($users as $user) {
        # Find each user
        $user = User::findOrFail($user);

        # Authorize
        $this->authorize('delete', $user);

        # Delete user
        $user->delete();
    }

    return response()->json([
        'success' => true,
        'message' => 'User deleted!'
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Did you try the same but using policy middlewares instead? You could give it a try by removing the uthorization logic in your controller and adding `->can('delete', User::class)` in your route definition. This will make your route to use the UserPolicy class. https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/authorization#via-middleware
BTW, I'm working on the exact same thing right now and moving policy logic to routes makes controllers a little bit clean.

Comment: Just tried, and it didn't work at all, sadly. I have bit of a different setup when doing deletions. I have my custom made responsive vue table that does single and bulk deletions of models on the same method (destroy). Will post the method as an edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by using `error.response.data.message` instead of `response.message` in the axios catch method.